# Is there an easier way to write a bubble sort algorithm in masm modular style?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, assembly, masm

I wrote a bubble sort algorithm in assembly, I'm proud of myself, but at the same time I think my bubble sort is wrong.

Can someone let me know if it's right? And how do I make my program more modular so I can reuse it later?

```
 .386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 100h

printf proto c arg1:ptr byte, printlist:vararg

.data

array dword 8,9,10,40,80,0
fmtmsg2 db 0dh,0ah,0
fmtmsg1 db "%d ",0

.code


public main

main proc

      mov ecx,0
      mov edx,0
      mov esi,offset array
innerloop:

      inc ecx            
      cmp ecx,5          
      je outerloop       
      mov eax,[esi]      
      cmp eax,[esi + 4]  
      Jge noexchange        

      ;exchange values   
      xchg eax,[esi+4]   
      mov [esi],eax      
  noexchange:
      add esi,4           
      jmp innerloop          

outerloop:
     mov esi,offset array

     ;inner loop counter
     mov ecx,0 

     ;outer loop counter
     inc edx     

     cmp edx,5
     jne innerloop

     ;loop 3 counter
     mov edx,0

     ;load array offset
     mov esi,offset array

loop3:

     mov eax,[esi]
     push edx
     invoke printf,addr fmtmsg1,eax
     pop edx

     add esi,4
     inc edx
     cmp edx,5
     jne loop3

     invoke printf,addr fmtmsg2

     ret
main endp

end main
```

Comment: _'Let me know if it's right'_ - we aren't here to do your testing for you.

Comment: Post the declaration of the array.

Comment: If you're looking for feedback on the code rather than help with the code, I'd suggest migrating this to codereview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original algorithm works great (congratulations). It sorts an array in descending order, for example, if array is [1,2,3,4,5] the result is [5,4,3,2,1]. If you want it in ascending order, just change one instruction. I used Visual Studio 2010, but the code is the same (my changes are pointed by arrows, but you only need one change: "jbe") :

```
void death_reverse () {
int array[5] = { 5,4,3,2,1 };        // <=====================
__asm {          mov ecx,0
                  mov edx,0
                  lea esi, array        // <=====================
            innerloop:

                  inc ecx            
                  cmp ecx,5          
                  je outerloop       
                  mov eax,[esi]      
                  cmp eax,[esi + 4]  
                  Jbe noexchange         // <=============== ASCENDING ORDER.

                  ;exchange values   
                  xchg eax,[esi+4]   
                  mov [esi],eax      
              noexchange:
                  add esi,4           
                  jmp innerloop          

            outerloop:
                 lea esi, array        // <=====================

                 ;inner loop counter
                 mov ecx,0 

                 ;outer loop counter
                 inc edx     

                 cmp edx,5
                 jne innerloop

                 ;loop 3 counter
                 mov edx,0

                 ;load array offset
                 lea esi, array        // <=====================

            loop3:

                 mov eax,[esi]
                 push edx
                 invoke printf,addr fmtmsg1,eax
                 pop edx

                 add esi,4
                 inc edx
                 cmp edx,5
                 jne loop3

                 invoke printf,addr fmtmsg2
}
}
```